# Firebase FCM giving Internal Server Error 6/10 times

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented Firebase FCM for push notifications in my app, and it works great - except from, as my topic describes, it gives me this response aprox 6/10 times:

```
{
    error = InternalServerError;
}
)
, "multicast_id": 8370179651570531666, "failure": 1, "canonical_ids": 0, "success": 0]
```

The rest of the times, it delivers the notification as expected!

I'm sending my notifications from my app, through https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send as a POST-request like this:

```
func sendFcmNotificationToUser(title: String, message: String, to: String, sound: Bool, badge: Bool) {

// Prepare json data
let mapDict = ["title": title, "body": message, "badge": 1, "sound": "default"]
let json = ["priority": "high", "notification": mapDict, "to": to]

do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(json, options: .PrettyPrinted)

    // create post request
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = jsonData

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("__111 \(error!.description)")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let responseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print("__222 \(responseJSON)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed2222")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
} catch {
    print("Failed11111")
}
}
```

I have googled around, but haven't been able to find a solution to this - so my guess is, that it's a Firebase problem. Have anyone of you experienced the same?

I guess that my solution will be to check the response for this error, and if it occurs, I'll send the request again, until it succeeds.. Also maybe add a timer, to add a little delay between my requests. Does that seem like a legit solution to you guys?

Otherwise I don't really know what to do :-)

Just some bonus info: 
When I send messages/notifications from the FCM console, it also only delivers sometimes.. But if I send from an APNs tester directly from my Mac, it delivers every time, so my APNS certificate seems to work properly!

Have a lovely day :-)

Comment: I am seeing a lot of these errors right after a token is generated for the device. Usually after about 5min from the device registration the delivery works fine. Is that what you are seeing as well?

Answer (score 0):

As [lkraider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719993/firebase-fcm-giving-internal-server-error-6-10-times#comment68729068_40719993) said:

> I am seeing a lot of these errors right after a token is generated for the device. Usually after about 5min from the device registration the delivery works fine. Is that what you are seeing as well?